# How many approved reviews are required to get an edit applied for a question/answer?

Tags: discussion, support

I see suggested edits need to be reviewed for them to get applied on the post. How many such reviews are needed for every edit? Does this anyhow depend on the post(question/answer), or the reputation of the asker/respondant, or the reputation of the reviewer?

I recently found an edit of mine already approved by one but still pending review.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work) (specifically, [the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/76284/274942)):

> - Two (or three on SO) accept or reject votes are required to remove the suggested edit from the queue and either apply the edit to the post or discard it. [It used to be a single vote (two on SO)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/151586/59303)

An edit will get approved if two out of three reviewers approve it, and rejected if two out of three reviewers reject it. The exception is if one of the reviewers is the original poster, in which case they can singlehandedly approve or reject the edit.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a "best of three" system, i.e. 2 approvals means it gets implemented, while 2 rejections means it gets discarded.

Comment: Mine got rejected at 1 rejection....http://physics.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/96823  What about this????